# Reclassify raster data based on specified values in a field

Tags: raster, pyqgis, vector, elevation, reclassify

I am building a processing plugin that uses elevation values from a shapefile to reclassify a raster data file.

###### Desired Table Group Condition

A: every unique value is treated as a group, and assign the new groups an individual ID number respectively.;
B: group the Unique values by 2 (the first two values), in ascending order, and so on, and assign the new groups an individual ID number respectively.;
C: group the Unique values by 3(the first three values), in ascending order, and so on, and assign the new groups an individual ID number respectively;
D: group the Unique values by 5(the first five values), in ascending order, and so on, and assign the new groups an individual ID number respectively;
E: group the Unique values by 10(the first ten values), in ascending order, and so on, and then assign the new groups an individual ID number respectively.

###### My Code

```
def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
    
input_raster = self.parameterAsRasterLayer(parameters, self.INPUT_RASTER, context)
input_vector = self.parameterAsVectorLayer(parameters, self.INPUT_VECTOR, context)

reclass_field_name = self.parameterAsString(parameters, self.RECLASS_FIELD, context)# the field values to be used for classifying
table_group = parameters[self.TABLE_GROUP] # the enum parameter. Here is supposed to specify how the values in the attribute field are to be grouped

output_raster = self.parameterAsOutputLayer(parameters, self.OUTPUT_RASTER, context) # output raster

feedback.setProgressText(self.tr('Reclassifying raster...'))

reclass_rules = {} # Initializes an empty dictionary to store the reclassification rules.
unique_values = set() # Initializes an empty set called unique_values to collect the unique values from the attribute field.

# Collect unique values from the attribute field
for feature in input_vector.getFeatures():  ## Iterates through each feature (row) in the input vector layer using the getFeatures() method.
    group_value = feature[reclass_field_name] 
    unique_values.add(group_value)

# Determine the number of unique values to consider based on table_group
if table_group == 0:
    num_unique_values = len(unique_values)
elif table_group == 1:
    num_unique_values = 2
elif table_group == 2:
    num_unique_values = 3
elif table_group == 3:
    num_unique_values = 5
elif table_group == 4:
    num_unique_values = 10

# Sort the unique values in ascending order
sorted_unique_values = sorted(unique_values)

# Populate the reclass_rules dictionary
for i in range(num_unique_values):
    if i < len(sorted_unique_values):
        reclass_rules[sorted_unique_values[i]] = i + 1

# Apply reclassification rules to the raster
output_array = self.apply_reclassification(input_raster, reclass_rules)

output_raster.dataProvider().setBlock(1, output_array)

return {self.OUTPUT_RASTER: output_raster}

def apply_reclassification(self, input_raster, reclass_rules):

raster_provider = input_raster.dataProvider()
width = input_raster.width()
height = input_raster.height()
block_size = 256  # Choose an appropriate block size
        
output_array = np.empty((height, width), dtype=np.float32)
        
for block_y in range(0, height, block_size):
    for block_x in range(0, width, block_size):
        block_width = min(block_size, width - block_x)
        block_height = min(block_size, height - block_y)
        
        # Read the block data
        input_block = raster_provider.block(block_x, block_y, block_width, block_height)
                        
        output_block = np.vectorize(lambda x: reclass_rules.get(x, x))(input_block)                
        output_block = np.where(np.isnan(output_block), input_block, output_block)  # Handle NaN values
        
        output_array[block_y:block_y + block_height, block_x:block_x + block_width] = output_block
                                     
return output_array
```

I want to use the selection value from the `GROUP_TABLE` tab condition to set the reclassification rules from the attribute field (i.e.= `RECLASS_FIELD`) in the vector layer (`INPUT_VECTOR`) such that it performs the reclassification, and generates the output raster based on the group value selected. This is what I want.

###### Error Message

```
line: in apply_reclassification
input_block = raster_provider.block(block_x, block_y, block_width, block_height)
TypeError: QgsRasterDataProvider.block(): argument 2 has unexpected type 'int'
```

Comment: According to [the documentation of QgsRasterDataProvider.block()](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsRasterDataProvider.html#qgis.core.QgsRasterDataProvider.block), the second argument should be a bounding box of type QgsRectangle.

Comment: @Matt, Thank you for looking into my concerns. Can you help me fix it? I  have read the documentation you referred to, but am still struggling with my code.  Thank you.